# Can I post a suggestion for a stack app?

Tags: support, app-request, meta, script-request

I have an idea for a stack app. However, I can't program it. Can I post an app suggestion?

Comment: Oops. Answered here before I realized it was a dupe.  The dupe's answers are mostly opinion polling, alas, as specifically stated with verbiage like `"My humble opinion:"` in half the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **read and thoroughly understand** both:

- [What topics can I ask about here? (Stack Apps)](https://stackapps.com/help/on-topic)
  and
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking? (Stack Apps)](https://stackapps.com/help/dont-ask)

That said, **you *can* propose** changes to the API, or request apps, or request scripts.
Keep in mind that this site is not an app/script writing service and almost everyone here is a volunteer.

It would be better if you **ask for help solving a particular, Stack Exchange related *need*** that you think could be solved with an app or script.

## A good app/script request:

1. Has a clear, actionable description of the desired result. Pictures help.
2. Clearly aims to improve the use of Stack Exchange sites and/or Stack Exchange data.
3. Has broad appeal and/or looks to be something fun or interesting to program/answer.
4. Avoids ["X Y problems"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). State your desired *result* in terms that don't depend on how you think it can be accomplished.  For specific programming questions, ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

## Tag your request with one or more of:

[app-request](/questions/tagged/app-request), [script-request](/questions/tagged/script-request), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and/or [support](/questions/tagged/support), as appropriate.
(Additional tags may apply as well. EG [answers](/questions/tagged/answers), etc.)